# Dynamically add an event to Highcharts series

Tags: events, highcharts

I am able to create my Highchart:

```
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(WhateverOptions);
```

I am able to dynamically set the function to execute when the user puts his cursor on a point:

```
   chart1.tooltip.options.formatter = function() {
     return 'Whatever I want to display in the tooltip';
   }
```

I am looking for a way to specify the function to execute when the user **clicks** on a point.
  I need to specify this function dynamically, just like for the tooltip.
  I don't want to set the event as part of the options when creating my chart.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar scenario in my application.

Actually, I generate all data server-side with a json builder which does not allow me to write pure javascript inside my template. Moreover, I am using the same template for 10+ different graphs across several pages, but I do not want to assign the same behavior to all of them.

Thus, I needed to access and edit the *onclick* event for all points in my chart.

```
var chart = $('#graph-container').highcharts();
// Iterate over the chart series in order to assign a point click event option
chart.series.forEach(function(s){
  s.options.point.events = {
    click: function(){
       // Store the point object into a variable
       var $$ = this;
       // Get the corresponding date in the from my x value
       var date = new Date($$.series.points[$$.index].x);
       // Do something with the date found
       console.log(date);
    }
  }
})
```

This should work with Highcharts 5.x

Comment: In case anyone ends up here like I was trying to do it on the series rather than point level, you can do it but it seems you have to use userOptions not options:
      chart.series[0].userOptions.events = {
            click: () => console.log("triggered")
        }

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts gives you a click event i the series object http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.click.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        alert(this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

To add this dynamically, I would just call a dummy function in the main chart click event, which does nothing, then redefine that function to do what you want when you want to add the click functionality.

Comment: Thanks SteveP, but, as stated in my question, I don't want to set this option at chart creation but add it dynamically on an existing chart. Just like the tooltip example shows.

Comment: That looks hard. I've suggested a work-around which is to define a dummy function which does nothing on click when first creating the chart, and then re-defining it when you want to add some click functionality.

Comment: unfortunately dynamically add events is not possible, only what you can do is redraw chart with new options paraemter. Also you can use update() function http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update() which allows to update some of series parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For individual points you can use

```
    $(chart.series[0].data[0]).on('click', function() {
        alert('First Point Click!');
    });
```

And for all points in series:

```
    $(chart.series[0].data).on('click', function() {
        alert('Series Point Click')
    });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rinatio/ZFg3k/)